# Make :after element only if there is another element after it

Tags: html, css

I want to have after elements only if there are other elements after it.
Here is my code so far:

```
<table id='table_1'>
   <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
 </tr> 
</table>
```

Is it possible to have :after after A and B, but not C?

My CSS

```
#table_1 td:after{
content: "";
background: black;
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easiest** way to do it is to use the not(:last-child):

```
#table_1 td:not(:last-child):after{
    content: "";
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**[Working exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/ak2o19nk/)**

That way you have **only one** selector and you don't need to override your code.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `:before` with `+` for older browsers support

[Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```css
#table_1 td {
  position: relative;
}
#table_1 td + td:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id='table_1'>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Putting something “after” an element is not the same as putting something “before” the next element, since the pseudo-elements appear *inside* the real element (after or before its real content). So this might be an interesting different approach, but as such not an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `td:last-child` to select any `td` element that is the last child of its parent element, and then hide its `:after` pseudo-element:

```
#table_1 td:last-child:after {
    display:none;
}
```

Demo:

```css
#table_1 td:after {
    content:"";
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#table_1 td:last-child:after {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<table id='table_1'>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```